# How to use Java CriteriaBuilder's notLike method when comparing tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteriabuilder

I have two Entity's.

Recipe:

```
@jakarta.persistence.Entity 
public class Recipe implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@jakarta.persistence.Id @jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String name;

private String instructions;

private Boolean isVegetarian;

private String numberOfServings;

@jakarta.persistence.OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Valid
private List<@Valid Ingredient> includedIngredients = new ArrayList<>();

@jakarta.persistence.OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Valid
private List<@Valid Ingredient> excludedIngredients;

public Recipe() {
  super();
}
```

Ingredient:

```
@jakarta.persistence.Entity
public class Ingredient implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@jakarta.persistence.Id @jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String name;

private Boolean required;

public Ingredient() {
  super();
}
```

I've created a CriteriaBuilder to allow users to find recipes that only have certain ingredients. Eg. Find me all recipes that have "Garlic" and "Onions".

I have successfully done that:

```
List<Predicate> ingredientsPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

for (Ingredient ingredient : fields.getIncludedIngredients()) {
    ingredientsPredicates.add(builder.like(builder.lower(recipe.get("includedIngredients").<String> get("name")), "%" + ingredient.getName().toLowerCase() + "%"));
}

allPredicates.add(builder.or(ingredientsPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));
```

However, I also need to allow the user to find recipes that do NOT contain certain ingredients. Eg. Find me all recipes that don't have "Garlic" and "Onions".

I thought something similar would work, but no such luck....I was able to successfully use the 'notLike' method for the Recipe name, but not for the includedIngredients. Any ideas? I tried this:

```
List<Predicate> ingredientsPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

for (Ingredient ingredient : fields.getExcludedIngredients()) {
    ingredientsPredicates.add(builder.notLike(builder.lower(recipe.get("includedIngredients").<String> get("name")), "%" + ingredient.getName().toLowerCase() + "%"));
}

allPredicates.add(builder.or(ingredientsPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));
```

Comment: Is this really related to the SQL _language_? I see no SQL above, do you expect a SQL answer?

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/criteria-api-like-expressions.html

Comment: @jarlh Seeing the SQL query may help with my answer, so that is why I tagged SQL. How would you write the query in SQL?

Comment: @ΣωτήρηςΡαφαήλ Ha, I found this link already, but it did not help with this specific example :/

Comment: I have no idea what you want here. A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: @jarlh Maybe you can help me understand this then. If one recipe can point to many ingredients and one ingredient can point to many recipes then what is the relationship between the two? Is it a one-to-many to a one-to_many? I actually believe it's a many-to-many relationship